# Ordenar por columna cuando la columna no está en el modelo

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-admin

Estoy intentando poner el ordenar por columna, tipo pincho en dicha columna y te ordenar por ella, pero me da error al pinchar en la columna:
admin.py

```
list_display = ['link_name', 'show_empresa', 'show_titular_nombre', 'show_nombre_completo', 'show_titular_id', 'creado']

def show_nombre_completo(self, obj):
    if obj.titular and isinstance(obj.titular, seguro):
        return obj.titular.nombre_completo
    return ''
show_nombre_completo.short_description = 'Nombre'
show_nombre_completo.admin_order_field = 'titular__nombre_completo'
```

cuando pincho sobre la columna me salta este error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'nombre_completo' into field

Comment: Puedes adjuntar la definición de los modelos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he conseguido. Gracias a tod@s por intentarme ayudarme

```
show_nombre_completo.admin_order_field = 'titular__seguro__nombre_completo'
```

Un saludo